# Getting multiple field group by result in elasticserach using java api

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I have a json

```
{"id": 2,"name": "Chethan","address":"Banglore"}
```

Trying to groupby two fields id and name,

```
List<String> statFields = new ArrayList();
        statFields.add("name");
        statFields.add("id");

        // 2. bootstrap the query
        SearchRequestBuilder search = client.prepareSearch("student")
            .setSize(0).setFrom(0)
            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery());

        // 3. add a stats aggregation for each of your fields
        for (String field : statFields) {
            search.addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms(field+"_stats").field(field));
        }

        // 4. execute the query
        SearchResponse response = search.execute().actionGet();

        for(String field : statFields) {
        Terms termAgg = (Terms) response.getAggregations().get(field+"_stats");

        for (Terms.Bucket entry : termAgg.getBuckets()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " **** " + entry.getDocCount()); // Doc count
        }
        }
```

Below is the response

```
chethan**** 2
Raj**** 1
Mohan**** 1
1 **** 1
2 **** 1
3 **** 1
```

But I need combined response like sql,

```
name    id     count
chethan 1         1
```

is it possible through elasticsearch java api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have used `subAggregation` plus use `keyword` type for aggregations.

[Java Rest High-Level Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-search.html)

Assuming your mappings look like:

```
PUT student
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "address": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In order to `group by` **name** and **id** you should use this query (low level query):

```
GET student/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },"aggs": {
        "id": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "id",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In java the query above is similar to:

```
SearchResponse response = client.search(new SearchRequest("student")
    .source(new SearchSourceBuilder()
            .size(0)
            .aggregation(
                    AggregationBuilders.terms("by_name").field("name.keyword")
                            .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("by_id")
                                    .field("id")
                            )
            );
```

If you want to use your code, probably something like that :

```
// 2. bootstrap the query
SearchRequestBuilder search = client.prepareSearch("student")
    .setSize(0).setFrom(0)
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery());

// 3. add a stats aggregation for each of your fields

TermsAggregationBuilder aggregation = AggregationBuilders.terms("name_stats").field("name.keyword");
aggregation.subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("id_stats").field("id"));  
search.aggregation(aggregation);


// 4. execute the query
SearchResponse response = search.execute().actionGet();


    Terms termAgg = (Terms)response.getAggregations().get("name_stats");

    for (Terms.Bucket entry: termAgg.getBuckets()) {
        if (entry.getDocCount() != 0) {
            Terms terms =entry.getAggregations().get("id");
            Collection<Terms.Bucket> buckets = terms.getBuckets();
            for (Bucket sub : buckets ) {
                System.out.println((int) sub.getDocCount());
                System.out.println(sub.getKeyAsString());
            }
        }
    }
```

I removed the `for` loop. you should design your own structure now that you have to use sub-aggregations.

**UPDATE**

Is this what you want?

```
GET student/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
    "aggs" : {
        "name_id" : {
            "terms" : {
                "script" : {
                    "source": "doc['name.keyword'].value + '_' + doc['id'].value",
                    "lang": "painless"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this is what you aimed for.

Comment: I've removed the second **for** loop and added code to get sub-aggregations.

Comment: Thank you Assael, name   and  id  will be dynamically populated for me(it can be variable number of parameters) I should group by those parameters and populate response in this format

name    id     count
chethan 1         1

In mysql equivalent to select a,b count(*) from table group by a,b;

Comment: So what is missing? the **for** loop?

Comment: If we group by name aggregation  the result is 
ABC**** 2
XYZ**** 1
LMN**** 1

if we group by id below is the result
1 **** 1
2 **** 1
3 **** 1
4 **** 1

How can I pass this to user? UI will be querying for group by columns  , I should return all the columns and respective count.

Comment: You have to define yourself which field is  the primary aggregation and and which one is the sub aggregation. i don't know if i understood your question.

Comment: How to combine primary aggregation and sub aggregation because I will be doing groupby for multiple fields , user interface  will  be showing that in grid. for example if they give me 3 columns as input I should do group by of all those column and send response back right?

Comment: This was mysql functionality,
select a,b count(*) from table group by a,b

 which I am porting to elasticsearch

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202556/discussion-between-assael-azran-and-chethan-bhounsley-g).

Comment: Perfect answer !!!! I was not knowing this can be achieved by sub aggregation. Thank you Assael